# How to make apex code and visual force page available in multiple languages

Tags: apex

I have a salesforce url coming from sites, when the user executes the URL in browser he can enter first name , last name, select a country from countries picklist, select a state from states picklist and hit the save changes button so when the page loads values are auto populated into the fields and then saved to object fields. I want this to be available in multiple languages, for ex. if a user from japan should see the text(static & dynamic), picklist values and field values only in his native language i.e japanese. I am sorry I have no idea on this else I would have posted a code to work on.

Comment: Here's a good post from Keith C. https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/multi-language-using-visualforce-with-custom-labels

Comment: https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_workbench_cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: @SL, what about the static text, does translation workbench handle that and the button text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Divya

Get the user local language from logged in user `[SELECT LanguageLocaleKey FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId()]`

Use Language tag in `<apex:page>` (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_page.htm#d711936e74)
for e.g
`<apex:page language="{!userLocal}">` //userLocal is the property whose value you'll get from a query