# Form In Arabic Language With Picklist Values In Arabic As well

Tags: visualforce, controller, picklist, language

Hope all of you are doing good.

I want to create a visualforce page (form) which will take input and submit in database but this should be in Arabic. Everything inside form should be in Arabic including picklist values. Please give me some hint how I should start. I have an idea of the same with English but what approach I should choose for Arabic I have no idea.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: you have to use translate workbench https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/198/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_workbench_cheatsheet.pdf

Answer (score 2):

**Enable Language**

1. Arabic does not come by default. You need to enable it. Setup --> Company Profile --> Language Settings --> Enable "Enable End User Languages" --> 
   https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000182272&type=1
2. After that you would be able to use this Language for translation.

**Translate texts on VF Page:**

Use custom label for each hard-coded statement/unit of words. And after that translate that in Arabic. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cl_translate_edit.htm&r=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.in%2F&type=5

**Translate picklist value:**

Setup --> Translation workbench

1. Add Arabic in Translation Settings
2. Add picklist value for Arabic using translate section: https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2017/03/28/translate-picklist-into-multiple-languages/

Answer (score 1):

Here is how i would do it:

1. Defined required labels and their translations in translation workbench
2. Defined required labels their translations in translation workbench
3. Create VF page with labels

Here are links with details information.

[Multi language using visualforce with custom labels](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/57288/multi-language-using-visualforce-with-custom-labels)

https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2017/03/28/translate-picklist-into-multiple-languages/